# Некорректно работает отображение нажатий клавиш

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

При нажатии на F10 кнопка F10 на форме никак не реагирует, зато реагирует кнопка System(Win), также при нажатии на любую из двух кнопок Alt, они никак не реагируют, но при нажатии RCtrl и RAlt одновременно RAlt все таки реагирует, в чем может быть проблема ?

```
    private void WinKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.F10:// F10
                {
                    F10.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
            //SpecialKeys------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //SpecialKeys------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //SpecialKeys------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            case Key.Escape:// ESC
                {
                    Escape.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
            case Key.Back:// Backspace
                {
                    Backspace.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
            case Key.Tab:// Tab
                {
                    Tab.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
            case Key.Enter:// Enter
                {
                    Enter.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
            case Key.CapsLock:// CAPS
                {
                    Capslock.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
            case Key.LeftShift:// Left Shift
                {
                    LShift.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
            case Key.RightShift:// Right Shift
                {
                    RShift.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
            case Key.LeftCtrl:// Left Ctrl
                {
                    LCtrl.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
            case Key.System:// Win
                {
                    Sys.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
            case Key.LeftAlt:// Left Alt
                {
                    LAlt.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
            case Key.Space:// Space
                {
                    SpaceBar.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
            case Key.RightAlt:// Right Alt
                {
                    RAlt.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
            case Key.RightCtrl:// Right Ctrl
                {
                    RCtrl.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
            case Key.Apps:// Menu
                {
                    Apps.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void WinKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.F10:// F10
                {
                    F10.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
            //SpecialKeys------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //SpecialKeys------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //SpecialKeys------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            case Key.Escape:// ESC
                {
                    Escape.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
            case Key.Back:// Backspace
                {
                    Backspace.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
            case Key.Tab:// Tab
                {
                    Tab.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
            case Key.Enter:// Enter
                {
                    Enter.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
            case Key.CapsLock:// CAPS
                {
                    Capslock.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
            case Key.LeftShift:// Left Shift
                {
                    LShift.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
            case Key.RightShift:// Right Shift
                {
                    RShift.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
            case Key.LeftCtrl:// Left Ctrl
                {
                    LCtrl.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
            case Key.System:// Win
                {
                    Sys.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
            case Key.LeftAlt:// Left Alt
                {
                    LAlt.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
            case Key.Space:// Space
                {
                    SpaceBar.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
            case Key.RightAlt:// Right Alt
                {
                    RAlt.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
            case Key.RightCtrl:// Right Ctrl
                {
                    RCtrl.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
            case Key.Apps:// Menu
                {
                    Apps.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Вот XAML код :

```xml
<Window x:Class="Keyboard_Setup.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Keyboard Setup" Height="720" Width="1280"
    Background="Black"
    PreviewKeyDown="WinKeyDown"
    PreviewKeyUp="WinKeyUp">
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <Button x:Name="F10" Content="F10" Background="Gray" Width="48" Height="50" Canvas.Top="30" Canvas.Left="678"/>
        <Button x:Name="RShift" Content="Shift" Background="Gray" Width="154" Height="50" Canvas.Top="265" Canvas.Left="680"/>
        <Button x:Name="LCtrl" Content="Ctrl" Background="Gray" Width="60" Height="50" Canvas.Top="320" Canvas.Left="30"/>
        <Button x:Name="Sys" Content="Win" Background="Gray" Width="60" Height="50" Canvas.Top="320" Canvas.Left="96"/>
        <Button x:Name="LAlt" Content="Alt" Background="Gray" Width="60" Height="50" Canvas.Top="320" Canvas.Left="162"/>
        <Button x:Name="SpaceBar" Content="" Background="Gray" Width="320" Height="50" Canvas.Top="320" Canvas.Left="228"/>
        <Button x:Name="RAlt" Content="Alt" Background="Gray" Width="64" Height="50" Canvas.Top="320" Canvas.Left="554"/>
        <Button x:Name="Apps" Content="Menu" Background="Gray" Width="134" Height="50" Canvas.Top="320" Canvas.Left="624"/>
        <Button x:Name="RCtrl" Content="Ctrl" Background="Gray" Width="70" Height="50" Canvas.Top="320" Canvas.Left="764"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Если e.Key == Key.System, проверьте значение `e.SystemKey`. В реальности Key.System это не Win, это индикатор для `e.SystemKey`

Comment: И вправду, исправил case Key.System,на Key.Lwin, и теперь кнопка Win отображается корректно, но при нажатии на любою из двух кнопок Alt, не реагирует ни одна кнопка. Кнопка Alt загорится только если она будет нажата вместе с Ctrl, в ином случае никакой реакции. @aepot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил такую проверку для всех кнопок которые не отображались как нужно, а отзывались к SytemKey в оба метода WinKeyDown и WinKeyUp соответственно только с разными цветами окрашивания кнопки. И всё стало работать как надо.

```
        if(e.SystemKey == Key.RightAlt)
        {
            RAlt.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
        }
        if(e.SystemKey == Key.F10)
        {
            F10.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
        }
        if(e.SystemKey == Key.LeftAlt)
        {
            LAlt.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
        }
```

Также вместо case Key.System сделал case Key.Lwin
После этого она стала отображаться корректно.